# How to get week start date (Sunday) from Date column in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to get week start date from Sunday but not able to get that by using lambda:

```
lite['week_start']=lite['invoice_date.1'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)
```

Comment: Hi! To help us find the answer, we need to be shown examples of input data and the expected output please !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually I have a data set in which week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday, but, I wanted my week to be started on Sunday and end on Saturday.

Comment: @aasif did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Check the pd.to_period documentation: there you will find a link for pandas’ **offset strings**

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

Look for Anchored offsets:

`W-SUN` weekly frequency (Sundays). Same as `W`

`W-SAT` will do it for you:

```
lite['week_start'] = lite['invoice_date.1'].dt.to_period('W-SAT').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)
```

Week ends on Saturday and begins on Sunday.

Comment: Hi guardian, thankyou so much for your solution. It is working!

Comment: @aasif I’m glad to hear it. Please accept the answer above in order to close this question and recognize the author for his answer